# How to extract the "enum type" out of a properties from an interface?

Tags: typescript, react-tsx

I have a React interface, ex: TextStyle. And I need to use a dynamic value like textAlign. But this text align has to match the interface enum. How do I do this?

I have tried `typeof TextStyle["textAlign"]` but I get `'TextStyle' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

```
// @see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style
export interface TextStyle extends TextStyleIOS, TextStyleAndroid, ViewStyle {
    color?: string;
    fontFamily?: string;
    fontSize?: number;
    fontStyle?: "normal" | "italic";
    /**
     * Specifies font weight. The values 'normal' and 'bold' are supported
     * for most fonts. Not all fonts have a variant for each of the numeric
     * values, in that case the closest one is chosen.
     */
    fontWeight?: "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";
    letterSpacing?: number;
    lineHeight?: number;
    textAlign?: "auto" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify";
    textDecorationLine?: "none" | "underline" | "line-through" | "underline line-through";
    textDecorationStyle?: "solid" | "double" | "dotted" | "dashed";
    textDecorationColor?: string;
    textShadowColor?: string;
    textShadowOffset?: { width: number; height: number };
    textShadowRadius?: number;
    testID?: string;
}
```

I want to extract the enum out of the TextStyle interface to have `type TextAligEnum = "auto" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify";`

For example:

```
const renderX = ({
  title = "title",
  textAlign = "center"
}: {
  title: string;
  textAlign?: typeof TextStyle["textAlign"];
                     ^^^^^^^^^ 'TextStyle' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
}) => {
  return (
      <Text style={{ textAlign }]}>
        {title.toUpperCase()}
      </Text>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `typeof`, just use `TextStyle["textAlign"]` by itself.

```js
const renderX = ({
  title = "title",
  textAlign = "center"
}: {
  title: string;
  textAlign?: TextStyle["textAlign"];
}) => {
  return (
      <Text style={{ textAlign }]}>
        {title.toUpperCase()}
      </Text>

  );
};
```

The `typeof` takes an identifier of a value and returns its type. But `TextStyle` is already a type, which is why it cannot be used with typeof.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TextStyle["textAlign"]` as a type:

```
interface TextStyle {
    color?: string;
    fontFamily?: string;
    fontSize?: number;
    fontStyle?: "normal" | "italic";
    fontWeight?: "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";
    letterSpacing?: number;
    lineHeight?: number;
    textAlign?: "auto" | "left" | "right" | "center" | "justify";
    textDecorationLine?: "none" | "underline" | "line-through" | "underline line-through";
    textDecorationStyle?: "solid" | "double" | "dotted" | "dashed";
    textDecorationColor?: string;
    textShadowColor?: string;
    textShadowOffset?: { width: number; height: number };
    textShadowRadius?: number;
    testID?: string;
}


const a1: TextStyle["textAlign"] = "left"; // ok
const a2: TextStyle["textAlign"] = "center"; // ok
const a3: TextStyle["textAlign"] = "middle";  // error
```

Comment: Oh, didn't try that one. Thanks